# how to extract HTML data from a webpage which scrolls down for a fixed number of times?

Tags: java, html, scroll

I want to extract HTML data from a website using JAVA. The problem is the webpage keeps scrolling down once the user reaches the bottom of the page. Number of times it scrolls down is fixed. My JAVA code can extract only for the 1st part. How do I extract for the remaining scrolls? Is there a way to load the whole page at once with JAVA? ANy help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Is this a Java desktop plugin using JRE, or a headless / server-side component?

Comment: Could you provide a little more detail on how it works? Is Java using the equivalent of CURL to grab the html of a web page, or is it taking screenshots?

Comment: For extracting the webpage contents I use Jsoup library.

Answer (score 0):

This might be the type of thing that PhantomJS (http://phantomjs.org/) was designed for. It will crawl entire web pages and even execute JavaScript, using a "real" browser in headless mode. I suggest stopping what you're doing with Java and take a look at PhantomJS instead. It could save you a LOT of time. :)

Comment: my whole project is in Java, at this stage it would be difficult to change it to another platform. I am using Jsoup library to extract the contents of the webpage.

Comment: Ok I'm going to venture a guess and say that you're talking about sites like Twitter, Facebook etc. where as you near the bottom of the page, more content loads? That is controlled via JavaScript. To work with that you NEED to use PhantomJS, as Jsoup does not execute JavaScript.

Comment: Yes i am talking about such sites, only thing here is that number of times a new page loads as you reach bottom of the page is fixed. Is there anyway to connect PhantomJS with JAVA?

Comment: Another issue is that if my idea works for a desktop application, I would like to convert it to an Android App which I dont think supports PhantomJS

Comment: It would probably be helpful to share exactly what "your idea" is. What is the user trying to accomplish with your app?

Comment: I want to extract all the comics from 9gag.com home page and view it from my app. I can extract from the 1st page but the subsequent pages, I am not able to do

Answer (score 0):

This type of behavior is implemented in the browser, interpreting the user's scrolling actions to load more content via AJAX and dynamically modifying the in-memory DOM in the browser.  Consider that your Java runs in a web container on the server, and that web container (i.e. Tomcat, JBoss, etc) provides a huge amount of underlying code so your app doesn't have to worry about the plumbing.

Conceptually, a similar thing occurs at the client, with the DHTML web page running in its own "container" (the browser), which provides a wealth of functionality, from UI to networking, to DOM, etc.  If you remove the browser from the equation and replace it with a Java program, you will need to provide the equivalent of the browser in which the DHTML/Javascript can execute.

I believe that HTMLUnit *may* fill the bill, but have not worked with it personally.